# Node.js's Buffer.writeFloatBE in Javascript ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, arraybuffer

I have the following code in Node.js:

```
  var number = parseFloat(-0.8);
  var buffer = new Buffer(4);
  buffer.writeFloatBE(number, 0);
  return -~parseInt(buffer.toString('hex'), 16) - 1;
```

How can I accomplish the same with ArrayBuffer in normal javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse IEEE754 writer from Buffer itself (it's now moved to C++ land, [link to JS implementation](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.6/lib/buffer_ieee754.js#L66))